# c++: Initialize vector of shared_ptr in constructor as different pointers

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

Here is what I have:

```
class A
{
    A(int i):_i(i){}

private:
    int _i;
};

class B
{
    B();

private:
    std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<A> > _v;
}
```

And I need to initialized `_v` with two `boost::shared_ptr<A>`s.

I tried this:

```
B::B():_v(2, boost::make_shared<A>(0)){}
```

But it seems that both pointer point to the sole created object - not what I need.

I don't have `c++11` so I can't use:

```
B::B():_v{boost::make_shared<A>(0), boost::make_shared<A>(0)}{}
```

What is the best solution for this situation?

Comment: Can't you just `push_back` twice?

Comment: `B::B(): _v(2) { _v[0] = boost::make_shared<A>(0); _v[1] = boost::make_shared<A>(0); }`

Comment: You could use `boost::assign::list_of`, e.g. `S() : v( list_of(make_shared<int>(0))(make_shared<int>(1)) ) {}` unfortunately, this is reported to be ambiguous (ctor of `v`; I don't know why) and can be resolved by an ugly `S() : v( vector<shared_ptr<int> >() = list_of(make_shared<int>(0))(make_shared<int>(1)) ) {} `

Comment: @DyP, thank you, I preferred Yakk's answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the creation of the `vector` into a function that returns a `vector`.

The cost of copying a `vector` of `shared_ptr` with 2 elements is going to be low enough that you won't care, and with NRVO and RVO it could be completely optimized out even in C++03.  (In C++11, if NRVO and RVO are blocked for whatever reason, it will only do moves).

```
 // if you make it a member, make it `static`:
 std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> > make_vector() {
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> > retval;
    retval.push_back( boost::make_shared<A>(0) );
    retval.push_back( boost::make_shared<A>(0) );
    return retval;
 }
 B::B():_v( make_vector() ) {}
```